# Raspberry Pi: seems fail to startup after I add one line to /etc/rc.local

Tags: raspberry-pi

I add one line to /etc/rc.local:

```
sudo python /home/pi/web/xxx.py
```

then restart the system. Unfortunately, I am never able to ping successfully the device!
Moreover, I could not ssh to the device to see any log on the system...

Anyone help me?

Comment: Then [plug a screen into it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/three-ways-to-display-your-raspberry-pi-on-a-monitor-or-tv/) and see what it's doing...

Comment: First do @TessellatingHeckler suggested.Then  remove sudo from the line . Then could you try once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another Linux pc try to mount your SD and edit the /etc/rc.local.

If the other pc doesn't have a SD slot, use a universal memory reader.

Take into account that the /etc/rc.local must exit with the status error 0.  And maybe your python script is failing and exiting with a different status error value.

By the way, your /home/pi/web/xxx.py script should be exacuted by the pi user, so your /etc/rc.local should have some like this:

```
sudo -u pi python /home/pi/web/xxx.py

exit 0
```

I hope it helps you.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks! By mounting SD card to another linux machine, I removed the line I added. Now the system boots successfully!